# Get the MIN(date) across all records BUT also getting SUM for each type

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data delimited by COMMA.

```
balance_date,name,wallet_type,available_balance

2020-05-07 13:28:59,wokalap,debit,12345
2020-06-02 08:07:18,wokalap,credit,1116
2020-06-02 08:07:18,wokalap,crypto,113
2020-05-06 59:10:05,wokalap,debit,55795
2020-06-07 08:07:18,wokalap,credit,1448
2020-06-05 08:07:18,wokalap,crypto,546
```

I want to get the SUM for each wallet_type but I also would ONLY want to get the earliest date across all the records and not for each wallet_type.

I am expecting this as a result:

| balance_date | name | wallet_type | available_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-06 59:10:05 | wokalap | debit | 68140 |
| 2020-05-06 59:10:05 | wokalap | credit | 2564 |
| 2020-05-06 59:10:05 | wokalap | crypto | 659 |

Please help figure out the correct script to produce such results. I am using mysql workbench for this.

Comment: Please clarify your question by updating the sample data and expected result based on the additional data you added to the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use sub-queries

```
SELECT
  (SELECT MIN(balance_date) 
   FROM mytable d1 WHERE d1.name = d.name) AS min_date, 
  name,
  wallet_type,
  SUM(available_balance) AS available_balance
FROM mytable d
GROUP BY name, wallet_type
```

Or if you are using MySQL version 8.0+, you could try window function

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  MIN(balance_date) OVER(PARTITION BY name) AS min_date, 
  name,
  wallet_type,
  SUM(available_balance) OVER(PARTITION BY name, wallet_type) AS available_balance 
FROM mytable
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/jsiBcYUD)

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery to find the minimum date, we can try the following simple aggregation:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT MIN(balance_date) FROM yourTable) AS balance_date,
       name,
       wallet_type,
       SUM(available_balance) AS total_balance
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    name,
    wallet_type;
```

Comment: Your edit was incorrect, as the OP seems to want the earliest balance date across the entire table.

Comment: It is not very clear but [for each new name](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/133656316?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the SUM for each wallet_type but I also would ONLY want
> to get the earliest date across all the records and not for each
> wallet_type.

This can be written as follows :

```
 select 
  subq.min_date as balance_date, 
  t.name, 
  t.wallet_type, 
  sum(t.available_balance) as available_balance
from 
  mytable t 
  join (
    select min(balance_date) as min_date from mytable
  ) subq 
group by 
  t.name, 
  t.wallet_type
  order by available_balance desc;
```

This gives me correct output as :

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|balance_date       | name   | wallet_type|  available_balance  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|2020-05-06 59:10:05| wokalap| debit      |  68140              |
|2020-05-06 59:10:05| wokalap| credit     |  2564               |
|2020-05-06 59:10:05| wokalap| crypto     |  659                |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a [demo using SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b33ef/6)

**Updates based on user input :**

When user inserts more sample data like this :

```
insert into mytable values 
('2020-05-07 13:28:59','wokalap','debit','12345'),
('2020-06-02 08:07:18','wokalap','credit','1116'),
('2020-06-02 08:07:18','wokalap','crypto','113'),
('2020-05-06 59:10:05','wokalap','debit','55795'),
('2020-06-07 08:07:18','wokalap','credit','1448'),
('2020-06-05 08:07:18','wokalap','crypto','546'),
('2020-05-07 13:28:59','pakalow','debit','12345'),
('2020-06-02 08:07:18','pakalow','credit','1116'),
('2020-01-01 08:07:18','pakalow','crypto','113'),
('2020-05-06 59:10:05','pakalow','debit','55795'),
('2020-06-07 08:07:18','pakalow','credit','1448'),
('2020-06-05 08:07:18','pakalow','crypto','546');
```

Expected output :

> would want is for the script to also get the MIN(date) for each new
> name being added on the table.

The query is as below :

```
select 
  subq.min_date as balance_date, 
  t.name, 
  t.wallet_type, 
  sum(t.available_balance) as available_balance
from 
  mytable t 
  join (
    select name, min(balance_date) as min_date from mytable
    group by name
  ) subq 
  on t.name = subq.name
group by 
  t.name, 
  t.wallet_type
order by available_balance desc;
```

Here is a demo using [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/243823/5)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have tried the script and it works great. But when I added some new data, with a balance date which is lower than '2020-05-06 59:10:05', I was not getting the desired results.

Please see this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/243823/1/0)

Comment: OK,
Let me check and modify it.
Do you have any such sample record ?

Comment: Yes, please see this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/243823/1/0)

Comment: I saw the demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/243823/1/0;    you have added exactly similar records for `name` = pakalow; And it gives similar results.

With `balance_date` as `2020-01-01 08:07:18`.

Can you help me to understand; what is wrong with result

Comment: Yes, what I would want is for the script to also get the MIN(date) for each new **name** being added on the table.

Comment: Well,
I have modified my query :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/243823/5   Can you check this demo ?
Please let me know, If I need to again sort / filter based on any column.

I have added the modified query to answer as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252570/discussion-between-tushar-and-wokalap).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a Simple Code that executes in MySQL. Please change it according to your database.

```
SELECT MIN(balance_date), ax.* FROM your_table my 
JOIN (
SELECT person_name, wallet_type, SUM(available_bal) 
FROM your_table GROUP BY wallet_type ) ax 
ON my.person_name = ax.person_name GROUP BY ax.person_name, ax.wallet_type;
```

No need for windows functions that are only supported in 8.0+ versions, the above query executes in any MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this simply without joins, using window functions and aggregation (assuming MySQL 8.0):

```
select min(min(balance_date)) over() as min_balance_date,
    name, 
    wallet_type, 
    sum(available_balance) available_balance
from mytable
group by name, wallet_type
```

In essence that's an aggregation query by name and wallet type, where the balance is summed. Then, we use window functions to compute the earliest date over all aggregates.

This scans the table only one, hence it is more efficient than options involving joins for example.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wx6Zu9Cx)**:

| min_balance_date | name | wallet_type | available_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-05-06 59:10:05 | wokalap | debit | 68140 |
| 2020-05-06 59:10:05 | wokalap | credit | 2564 |
| 2020-05-06 59:10:05 | wokalap | crypto | 659 |